# Is there a programm in Linux which will execute a command and send an email if it fails?

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I have a process which is started by Сron like this:

```
timeout 1h /app/longprocess.sh
```

Now I want to be notified by email if something goes wrong with it. Imagine this:

```
notifyme maintainer@example.org timeout 1h /app/longprocess.sh
```

where `notifyme` is a supposed command which will send an email to `maintainer@example.org` with the output of the command in case the command exits with a non-zero status. Is there something like this?

Comment: Usually `cron` already does that when there are failures/output from a `cron` job.  Why don't you just configure mail for your `cron` daemon?

Comment: What you propose is certainly in the realm of possibility for shell scripting (for non-enterprise level needs). BUT stackoverflow isn't a free coding service, AND we don't even support recommending software, tutorials etc. You need to post some code in attempt to solve your problem, and describe your debugging process by using small test cases, showing your expected results, your current results and any error messages you get. Please edit your question to follow the guidelines. Good luck.

Comment: @FatalError Actually cron doesn't send email when job fails but produces no output. But it's easy to produce some output. Just let the job be `job || echo "job failed"`.

Answer (score 2):

No, but (untested)

```
notifyme() {
    local recipient=$1
    shift
    output=$( "$@" 2>&1 )
    rc=$?
    echo "$output"
    if [[ $rc -ne 0 ]]; then
        mailx -s "Non-zero exit status ($rc) for command: $*" "$recipient" <<< "$output"
    fi
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you answer looks promissing. Can you remove "No" at the beginning of your answer, cause meanwhile I found some tools that a able to do that: 1) http://web.taranis.org/shush/ 2) http://www.uow.edu.au/~sah/cronwrap.html

Answer (score 1):

Use the logical `OR` operator `||`. When `||` is added to a command, whatever is listed **after** it will only get executed if the command listed **before** it returns a non-zero status (that is, if it errors out.) For example, using the code you provided:

```
timeout 1h /app/longprocess.sh || mail -s "job failed" maintainer@example.org
```

In the above command, `mail -s "job failed" maintainer@example.org` will **only** execute if `timeout 1h /app/longprocess.sh` is **not** successful.

Comment: The email will not include the output of the failed command: it will have an empty body.

Comment: In that case OP will have to get a bit more technical (or creative). I'd probably write the output of the script to a log file, and make the script throw an error (return a non-zero value.) You can then pipe the contents of the log file to the command in my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `||` operator as suggested in another answer, I recommend using `&&` and always pinging an external monitoring service. The monitoring service would alert you if a ping is missing. This has the benefit of also getting alerted if your cronjob didn't start up for whatever reason. One such monitor is [wdt.io](https://wdt.io).

Your cronjob would look something like

`timeout 1h /app/longprocess.sh && curl somemonitor.com/longprocess`